# How can I show the "Reformat code" dialog again in IntelliJ/PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I want to customize what the "Reformat code" action does in PhpStorm. The thing is that I can't do it because, in the past, I checked the "do not ask again" option.

How can I show that dialog again? I couldn't find anything in the menus or options, as well as the online help.

Answer (score 0):

What version do you use? In PHPStorm 9/10, you can hit `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+L` (see what action is assigned to 'Show reformat file dialog' in `Settings/Keymap/Other`) to see the dialog

Comment: That's so weird, using this shortcut (which is correctly mapped to `Show reformat file dialog` according to my settings) opens the "Find action" menu item… I swear I cannot understand what's happening, "Find action" is absolutely not mapped to anything close to the same shortcut… It seems to be a shortcut mapped to a now removed action?